# Function isn't returning the value, even though it's printing the correct value

Tags: java

I tried to find combinations of integers, however, my function isn't returning the list of combinations, but when I print the num variable it gives me the right values. Any help in this? This is the function below.

```
static int combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start,
                                int end, int index, int r) {
      if(index == r){
         String num = "";
         for (int i = 0; i<r; i++){
            num += Integer.toString(data[i]);
         }
         return Integer.parseInt(num);
      }

        for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++){
         data[index] = arr[i];
         combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
      }
      return 0;

   }
```

Comment: Only one "return" statement as the last line in a method! NOTE   the method system  your using is recursive (calls itself) beware of threading sequence issues if you use any. If you want to return the value, set the method return type for that, and if you want to return 1 or 0 with some other method, boolean primitive type is auto able to be interpreted as int

Comment: Please give some details about function arguments!

Comment: @HosseinTaghizad I used the program from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/ and I wanted to store the combination as a single integer, rather than print each one out.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant What would you suggest to do then?

Comment: So you mean if input array is {1, 2, 3, 4} and r is 2, then output should be only one integer like 121314232434 ?

Comment: I suggest you make a method to start your sequences of for loops as other methods and collect the answers from the processing mthods in that starter method.     https://blog.hubspot.com/website/java-return

Comment: @HosseinTaghizad I mean that, my combinations should come out as numbers, like 12 13 14 23 24 34

Comment: @SamuelMarchant oh okay i'll try to see that

Comment: In that case, the return type of `combinationUtil` must be an array or a list of integers **NOT** an integer value.

Comment: Around correct, an array, However you decide how to channel your program flow code, particularly because it's your modifications you want.

Comment: This makes no sense: your method `combinationUtil` returns an `int` when you want a list of combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to add each combination to a list instead of printing it:

```
public static void combinationUtil(int[] arr, int data[], int start,
                                   int end, int index, int r,
                                   List<int[]> list) {
    if (index == r) {
        list.add(Arrays.copyOf(data, r));
    } else {
        for (int i = start; i <= end && end - i + 1 >= r - index; i++) {
            data[index] = arr[i];
            combinationUtil(arr, data, i + 1, end, index + 1, r, list);
        }
    }
}
```